# Vue.js date filter to highlight if date if it's over due

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue filter that shows a "pretty" date. I would like the filter to highlight the date in red if it's overdue (date is less than current date).
Is there an easy way to do this in the filter or do I have to do it in the page?

My filter looks like this:

```
Vue.filter("date", function (value) {
  if (value === null || value === undefined) {
    return value;
  } else {
    const date = new Date(value);
    return date.toLocaleDateString(['en-GB']);
  }
});
```

Comment: Use class attribute https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Comment: How do I add a class from a filter? Or do you mean in the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

your template:

```
Your text bla bla bla <span :style="overDue">{{date}}</span>
```

js:

```
data:{
    date: "01/02/2019"
}

computed: (){
    overDue(){
        if(){ // your handler for overDue check.
            return 'color:red'
        }else return 'color:blue'
    }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to do it a bit more globally via a filter that was already in use, but this will work for me, thanks

Comment: Well, filters are used for manipulation of data values, not classes. 
If you need a global solution, I would suggest you to create dynamic component and pass date as a prop.
`Your text bla bla bla <overDue date="yourDateValue"></overDue>`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on VueJS filter [document](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html)

> Vue.js allows you to define filters that can be used to apply **common text formatting**.

but what you need is **style bindings** with some sort of condition.

You can defined a [methods](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#methods) that check if the date is valid and then call the method in [style bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax-1).

```
<span v-bind:style="{color: !isValidDate(date) ? '#F00' : '#000'}">{{date}}</span>
```